# Calculate resistance of a grid starting from equivalent resistance

Tags: resistors, network

Considering the attached picture how is possible to calculate single resistance value (R1,R2,R3,...) starting from equivalent resistance derived from nodes A-A', B-A', B-B', B-C', ...

Consider that in my real circuit I've 19 rows and 19 columns

[image]

Comment: Use star-delta transformation. [Link](http://www.ambrsoft.com/CalcElectric/Star2Delta/Star2Delta.htm)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible from an information point of view. You have 9 unknowns, and can make 9 independent measurements, so you have 9 equations to solve simultaneously. It's not clear to me that you can write equations to represent Rmeasured as a *linear* function of (R1, R2 etc), so the standard method of writing a matrix down and solving for it with normal linear algebra may not be available. However, optimising initial guesses for R1, R2 etc for the measured resistances will work, if slowly.

It will not be possible to get accurate results if the values of the resistors vary over a wide range. Consider the loop of resistors R1, R2, R4, R5. If R1 is 1 MΩ, and the others are 1 Ω, the measurement of R1 will always be dominated by the 3 Ω in shunt with it.

There is an alternative method to measure R1 etc, but you have to treat the terminals in a different way.

To measure R1 for instance, drive A with a known voltage. Connect a virtual ground amplifier to A' so that you can measure the current emerging while holding A' at ground. Connect all the other nodes to ground. Now all resistors in the network connected to A' have zero volts across them except R1, so this is the only resistor that will contribute an output current at A'. All the resistors connected to A are sending current to other grounded nodes. We know the voltage at A, so can compute R1. Compute all the other resistor values by driving the appropriate nodes. This is a standard technique called 'guarding', used in the automatic measurement of components on a populated PCB.

This method also suffers from a dynamic range problem in the real world, if the virtual ground amplifier has an offset voltage, as now A' to other nodes will not be zero volts, and some current can flow through other resistors. For similar sized resistors this error will be small, but if the 'undriven' resistors are ohms and the resistor being measured is MΩ, the error will be very large.